# Donde encuentro el codigo malicioso del virus JS/Coinminer.V?

Tags: javascript

Un cliente tiene una pagina web infectada con el virus de JS/Coinminer.V, quisiera saber en donde encuentro dichoso codigo, alguien sabe como podria hacerle para encontrarlo dentro del codigo de la pagina?

Comment: Prueba a buscar "coinhive" en los ficheros javascript que tenga

Comment: No aparece "coinhive"